# Height and width in Percentage is not working for cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` in my application where height and width are provided in percentage.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
   <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="5" class="table-viewport">
   ...
```

```
  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #e6e8f0;
  border-radius: 0.5%;
  /* box-shadow: 1px 100px black; */
  }
```

But it's not working. There is nothing visible on the screen. It works when we give the `height` and `width` in `px`.

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  height: 800px;
  width: 1300px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e8f0;
  border-radius: 0.5%;
  /* box-shadow: 1px 100px black; */
  }
```

Could anyone figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

The overscroll-behavior `css` property sets what a browser does when reaching the boundary of a scrolling area. It's a shorthand for `overscroll-behavior-x` and `overscroll-behavior-y`.

```css
overscroll-behavior: auto;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working as expected. I think the issue is not with the scrolling behavior, Any thoughts